# What are the major parts of a Tizen application's entry file?

Tags: c++, tizen

Because Tizen is still not so popular, I couldn't find Tizen application entry file explanation. Could anyone, based on the following example code, explain particular parts of Tizen entry file (Main function return value, #ifdef, args...)?

```
#include <new>
#include "MultipointTouch.h"

using namespace Tizen::Base;
using namespace Tizen::Base::Collection;

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif // __cplusplus

_EXPORT_ int OspMain(int argc, char* pArgv[]);

/**
 * The entry function of Tizen C++ application called by the operating system.
 */
int
OspMain(int argc, char* pArgv[])
{
    AppLog("Application started.");
    ArrayList args;
    args.Construct();
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        args.Add(*(new (std::nothrow) String(pArgv[i])));
    }

    result r = Tizen::App::Application::Execute(MultipointTouch::CreateInstance, &args);
    TryLog(r == E_SUCCESS, "[%s] Application execution failed", GetErrorMessage(r));

    args.RemoveAll(true);
    AppLog("Application finished.");
    return static_cast<int>(r);
}
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif // __cplusplus
```

Answer (score 0):

- `#ifdef __cplusplus`
  `extern "C`

Not Tizen-specific. What it does is to *"[make] a function-name in C++ have 'C' linkage (compiler does not mangle the name) so that client C code can link to (i.e use) your function using a 'C' compatible header file that contains just the declaration of your function."* ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/in-c-source-what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c/1041880#1041880)).

---

- `int OspMain(int argc, char* pArgv[])`

`OspMain` is simply the entry point for a Tizen native application (i.e. the first function in your app that the OS calls when your app starts), much like `main` or `WinMain` in other OSs/frameworks.

---

- args

The `App` `Execute` method [expects the arguments as a list of `Strings`](https://developer.tizen.org/help/topic/org.tizen.native.apireference/classTizen_1_1App_1_1UiApp.html#a7174aa4c36ad9d556de9488c8514b2bb). So the `OspMain` function takes care of building that list prior to calling the `Execute` method; a `String` is created from each `char*` in `argv`, and those `Strings` are placed in an [`ArrayList`](https://developer.tizen.org/help/topic/org.tizen.native.apireference/classTizen_1_1Base_1_1Collection_1_1ArrayList.html) (which is an implementation of the `IList` interface).

---

- return value

The return type of `OspMain` is `int`, but the result code it receives from `Execute` is of type `result`, so it casts the `result` to an `int`. There are [plenty of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=static_cast) on the topic of C++ casts if you want to read more about them.

---

In the end, I think there are very few instances where you'd have to care about the Entry file as an app developer. It's automatically created for you by the IDE and not something you'd typically change.